# VBA display MsgBox after InputBox

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox, msgbox

Messagebox not popping up after the inputbox.

```
Dim Output As Integer
Dim name As Variant
Output = MsgBox("Are You Interested in taking a short survey with me?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Short Survey")
If Output = vbYes Then
MsgBox "Great! I'll guide you through this"
name = InputBox("First Question, What's your name?")
If name = vbYes Then
MsgBox "Welcome"
Else
End If
Else
MsgBox "Thanks! But you can try again if you change your mind"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can Name be vbYes?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav just trying to use that to create a variable. Or what do you think?

Comment: "name" will be the result of your input box, you are treating using a msgbox return

Comment: Yeah, thanks! It's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `If name = vbYes Then` to `If name <> "" Then`

When you input some text, variable `name` gets *that text*, not `vbYes`.

```
Dim Output As Integer
Dim name As Variant
Output = MsgBox("Are You Interested in taking a short survey with me?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Short Survey")
If Output = vbYes Then
  MsgBox "Great! I'll guide you through this"
  name = InputBox("First Question, What's your name?")
  If name <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Welcome"
  End If
Else
  MsgBox "Thanks! But you can try again if you change your mind"
End If
```